# Overflow issue in flexbox

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, overflow

Markup & Styling

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 48px;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box-2 {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.overflow-container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.overflow-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
      <div class="box-1">This is 1</div>
      <div class="box-2">
        This is 2
        <div class="overflow-container">
          <div class="overflow-content">This is my overflow content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When using the `display: flex` property, the `overflow: auto` property doesn't function as expected. Instead, the size of the parent element expands to accommodate the width of the overflowing content. I'm seeking a solution to implement a horizontal scrollbar for the expanded content.
It does work as expected without flexbox

Comment: Add `min-width: 0;` for `.box2`.

Comment: @CBroe yes this works thanks
Although I'm not sure why I need `min-width: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

write this code in your parent class

```
#app {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **viewport width** property of **CSS**.
I have added **viewport width** propert in `#app` & `.box-2` class.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 48px;
  margin: auto;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}
.box-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box-2 {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50vw;
}
.overflow-container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.overflow-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
      <div class="box-1">This is 1</div>
      <div class="box-2">
        This is 2
        <div class="overflow-container">
          <div class="overflow-content">This is my overflow content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```